# How did the Lord Ruler do this?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn

Having just finished the Mistborn Secret History it seems to be made clear that

> the Lord Ruler died.

Yet it is also made clear in the Bands of Mourning that

> he in fact survived being killed in book one, escaped and stayed hidden through all of Ruin's plans and even the rebirth of the world.

The question is, how exactly has he done this when it conflicts with earlier information.

Answer (score 9):

He didn't.

Most of *Bands of Mourning* has a fair bit of misdirection running through it.  You are presented with the myth of the Bands as having the power of the Lord Ruler, and are led to believe that the images depicting that myth are also of the Lord Ruler.  They're not, and that several people call out the fact that this mythology makes no sense (the Lord Ruler with a spear?) is your tipoff that it is wrong.

This misdirection is reinforced when the Southerners are met, and they describe their savior that created the legend of the Bands, who came to them claiming he used to be the Sovereign and God.  It's still not Rashek, still not the Lord Ruler.

> It's Kelsier.  Kelsier survived being dead, and the story of what he went through is told in *Mistborn: Secret History*, a short novella whose existence wasn't even widely publicized until people reached the end of *Bands*.  It reveals that Kelsier found a way to preserve himself and influence events in the original trilogy, and implies that he and Spook found a way to get him back to the real world as well.  Rashek, the Lord Ruler, is even portrayed after death, and moved on wanting nothing further to do with the world.

Answer (score 1):

Its clear the lord ruler **Died** before the rebirth of the world, and that he **moved on**. WHO the Lord Ruler is after the rebirth of the world is a **mystery**, but we get clues at the end of Secret History that it may be Kelsier himself reborn. Notice the book ends with him attempting to regain a physical body.

This is most likely an identity we will learn in the next installment of the Wax and Wayne novels.

Its to be noted that Secret history was written as a way for Sanderson to re-introduce Keliser back into the Mistborn world and he will have a part to play yet.